# Disable TLS v1.0 in Cisco ISR4321/K9

Tags: security, cisco-isr, sslvpn

I would like to know the command on how I can disable the TLS v1.0 and v1.1 in the Cisco ISR4321/K9 and just retain TLS v1.2 ?

John

Comment: For which function/protocol?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to specify TLS version was added in IOS-XE 16.4.1 so you will want to make sure you have that version or later.

To specify version you can use the following commands:

```
ip http server tls-version TLSv1.2

ip http client tls-version TLSv1.2
```

Reference document: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/https/configuration/xe-16-5/https-xe-16-5-book/nm-nginx-http-web-security.html